# How do I make the Windows Remote Assistance window full screen accross two monitors?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-assistance

When a coworker sends me a remote assistance request and I connect to their machine it shows me both of their monitors at the same time in a single window. I can make this single window full screen by pressing CTRL+ALT+Break but then it full screens his two screens to a single one of my screens.

This looks like remote desktop and so there might be some configuration settings somewhere either in a file or in the registry that are the equivalent settings you would have with a remote desktop but that are specific to windows remote assistance.

Does any one know how to get this to full screen his two monitors across my two monitors or a way for him to share only a single monitor with me so that it looks correct?

Comment: Did you try to make your dual screen as only one?

Comment: If you are referring to making them one desktop with the total resolution of both screens, I don't know of a way to do that in windows 7. If your referring to just duplicating the desktop onto both screens then I can do that but then I only have one screen and more importantly the person I am connecting to would also have to do this for it to work fully.

Comment: Hmm i have the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Remote Assistance is not multi-screen aware and this is not possible.

At a stretch, you may be able to drag and make the application span across two screens but I am not sure that will work.

You can try looking in your graphics card driver to see if it supports a mode that basically allows your machine to act as one large screen instead of 2/3 smaller ones, however I think only Matrox display drivers can do that out the box.

Sorry I couldn't really be more help here.

Comment: I wonder if this is true for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "Actual Size" you will get the full screen size
which is much better than the two screens squashed into one window. 
Drag the scroll bars to view the other screen.

Squashed screen:

[image: Squashed Screen]

Actual size:

[image: Actual Size]